# Meteor Import JSON into Collection

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to import a JSON file that has embedded objects into the MongoDB and would like to know how to format to import the doc correctly. To be clear the doc format must remain in its current form. I must modify/create a function or method that would allow this file to be imported with _id associated in the sport-events array loop (Ive shorted to one sports-event array for brevity). Perhaps a better way of putting the question is how could I import eveything in the sports-event array and leave the rest of the doc.

JSON Doc.

```
{
"sports-content": {
    "sport-event": [{
        "event-metadata": {
            "league": "NCAA Basketball",
            "event-type": "0",
            "league-details": "NCAAB",
            "event-date-time": "12/18/2015 07:00 PM",
            "eventNum": "3000460",
            "status": "",
            "off-the-board": "False"
        },
        "team": [{
            "team-metadata": {
                "alignment": "Home",
                "nss": "526",
                "openNum": "526",
                "name": {
                    "full": "Clemson"
                }
            },
            "wagering-stats": {
                "wagering-straight-spread": {
                    "bookmaker-name": "BetOnline",
                    "active": "true",
                    "line": "1.5",
                    "money": "-110",
                    "context": "current"
                }
            },
            "team-stats": {
                "score": "0"
            }
        }, {
            "team-metadata": {
                "alignment": "Away",
                "openNum": "525",
                "nss": "525",
                "name": {
                    "full": "South Carolina"
                }
            },
            "wagering-stats": {
                "wagering-straight-spread": {
                    "bookmaker-name": "BetOnline",
                    "active": "true",
                    "line": "-1.5",
                    "money": "-110",
                    "context": "current"
                }
            },
            "team-stats": {
                "score": "0"
            }
        }]
    }],
    "sports-meta-data": {
        "doc-time": "42353.5979256944"
    }
  }
 }
```

Meteor server.js under Meteor.startup

```
if (SportEventsFeed.find().count() === 0) {
    console.log("Importing private/products.json to db")

    var data = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("ncaab.json"));

    data.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        SportEventsFeed.insert(item);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can just insert the items from the 'sports-event' array as individual documents in the db.
I'm not sure if the index value is what you wanted for the _id field, if not change the value assigned to item_id (or comment out this line for a default _id).

```
if (SportEventsFeed.find().count() === 0) {
  console.log("Importing private/products.json to db")

  var data = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("ncaab.json"));

  data['sports-content']['sports-event'].forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    item._id = index;
    SportEventsFeed.insert(item);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I ve tried several dot notation permutations and now just copied and pasted your answer just in case and I am still getting errors on the server side: ReferenceError: content is not defined

Comment: ahh, try this `data['sports-content']['sports-event']`

Comment: thanks. tried this with error-  data['sports-content']['sports-event'].forEach(function (item, index, array)- TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined......data.['sports-content']['sports-event'] - error Array.forEach Undefined....... data.['sports-content'].['sports-event'].forEach - error Array.forEach (native).

Comment: So the last version got the error: Array.forEach (native).

Comment: I went back to your original and tried it again this time without the index and it worked. Thank you!